# How do I recover a branch if I have deleted .git folder?

Tags: git, github

I made all my changes in a branch and made the commit and did a git push. After that I deleted my branch from github.com( i didnt delete it locally, i deleted it using the ui). After that I did a git checkout to my master and deleted my .git folder. These were a series of mistakes done by me, is it possible to recover my branch now? I tried running ease us on windows and got objects, remotes and logs folder only. Please suggest me if there is a way to recover/ restore the content of that branch. A lot depends on it.

Comment: It's lost :/  , I suggest you read some tuto before continuing with git

Comment: There are, of course, general tools to retrieve deleted files and folders depending on your OS.

Answer (score 3):

You are unfortunately out of options, unless one of the following happens to be true:

- Your branch formed part of a PR (in which case you can get back to the underlying commits via the GitHub UI).
- Someone else fetched the branch (in which case you can ask them to re-push it).

Answer (score 3):

.git directory is the directory which has all the version control history. If you delete that folder it is not longer version controlled, so you can't retrieve history anymore. Possibly if you deleted the folder and it's still in trash/recycle bin it could be a try to restore it and see if it works

Comment: Depending on what was deleted and how, it's possible that it's recoverable https://stackoverflow.com/a/65181667/1507124

Answer (score 2):

If you deleted your .git folder, you only have the files as they are lying on your file system right now. If you also deleted the remote branch on github, you have nothing that still stores the branch.

So, yeah, you successfully, permanently and irrevocably deleted your branch.